# html5 audio object ondurationchange not called on android

Tags: android, angularjs, html, audio, ionic-framework

I have build a angularjs directive to play audio files in a ionic application. I'm also displaying the duration of the audio file and stuff like that in my directive. So however if I want to display the duration of a audio file via the [ondurationchange Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondurationchange.asp) it works fine on iOS but on Android the event is never get called.

My code looks like this:

```
$scope.audioObj = new Audio(url);

if(isNaN(AAudioService.getDuration())) {
  $scope.audioObj.ondurationchange = function() {
  console.log($scope.audioObj.duration.toFixed(1));
}
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: Try to take a look [here](https://github.com/arielfaur/ionic-audio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Ionic-audio`](http://arielfaur.github.io/ionic-audio/) for this purpose. It internally uses the [`Cordova Media Plugin`](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media).

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jtJ3jkld8f4A15tOj2z0?p=preview).

**app.js**

```
//Add it as dependency
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'ionic-audio'])
```

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('MusicCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.track = {
        url: 'https://www.example.com/my_song.mp3',
        artist: 'Somebody',
        title: 'Song name',
        art: 'img/album_art.jpg'
    }
});
```

**yourtemplate.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Music">
  <ion-content>
      <ion-audio-track track="track">
          <div class="list list-inset">
              <div class="item item-thumbnail-left">
                  <img src="{{track.art}}">
                  <h2>{{track.title}}</h2>
                  <p>{{track.artist}}</p>
                  <ion-audio-controls>
                        <a class="button button-icon icon" ion-audio-play></a>
                        <ion-spinner icon="ios"></ion-spinner>
                    </ion-audio-controls>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <ion-audio-progress-bar display-time></ion-audio-progress-bar>
              </div>
          </div>
      </ion-audio-track>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```